# How do I go to and fro two individual windows forms without creating new instance for form1

Tags: c#, winforms

What I am trying to do here is :

1. I set up two windows forms. I added a button in both and textbox in form1 ( to verify preserved state)
2. I proceed and type gibberish in textbox
3. Now when I click the button in form1, it hides and shows form2
4. I have to go back to form1 now by clicking the button in form2 and I cannot create a new object in form2 since it will give me a new instance and text in texbox will be lost.

So how do I achieve to and fro movement in C# windows forms and preserve state.

Comment: When you say "go back" - are you trying to switch between the two repeatedly or just "pop" the second from the first? Would affect the logical structure a bit

Answer (score 1):

If you just call form1.Hide() your data in a textbox preserves until you show it again. The problem has to do with the way you hide your form1.

Answer (score 0):

Declare in yuor `Form2` ctor like this:

```
public class Form2 
{
    private Form form1 = null; 

    public Form2(Form1 frm1) 
    {
        form1 = frm1;
    }   

}
```

So you pass and save `Form1` object into `Form2` object. As soon as `Form2` finishes, it can use `form1` instance of `Form1` to show it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this just fine, as long as you are holding on to the forms objects themselves.

In other words, just use variables to keep the references to the actual forms themselves, and then hold on to them even after ShowDialog returns (assuming you want to show these modally).

Some Sample Code:

```
    private SampleForm m_oSamp1;
    private SampleForm m_oSamp2;

    private void SampleParentFunction()
    {

        if (m_bShowForm1)
        {
            m_oSamp1.ShowDialog();
            m_bShowForm1 = false;
        }
        else
        {
            m_oSamp2.ShowDialog();
            m_bShowForm1 = true;
        }

    }
```

The data in the individual forms is 100% independent and preserved if you do it like this.

Answer (score 0):

In form1:
In the class:

```
Form2 frm2=new Form2();
```

And the button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Hide();
    frm2.ShowDialog();
    Show();
}
```

In form2, the button:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Hide();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The situation that you describes involves in using `Binding` and separating the model(data) from the view using the `MVC` design pattern.

I recommend you to read about the pattern `MVC` and the `Binding` feature of WinForms.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding you correctly, but I don't see how this has anything to do with binding.